# USING Count() in a SELECT query with multiple INNER JOINS. Cannot find correct output

Tags: sql, select, count

This is my query:

```
select distinct 
    p.*,
    d.tech_id, 
    d.id, 
    prio.priority 
from
    data.curated_data s
inner join
    data.curated_details p on p.curated_scheme = s.curated_scheme 
                           and p.curated_category = s.curated_category
inner join
    data1.data_defn d on d.service_id = p.service_id
inner join 
    data1.data_priority prio on prio.ingest_data = d.ingest_data
                             and p.curated_scheme = %s
                             and s.manually_curated_flag = 'Y'
                             and s.autosuggest_kind = %s
limit %s
offset %s
```

This is what I tried to do:

```
select count(*) 
from ( select distinct p.*,
              d.tech_id, 
              d.id, 
              prio.priority 
       from data.curated_data s
       inner join data.curated_details p on p.curated_scheme = s.curated_scheme and p.curated_category = s.curated_category
       inner join data1.data_defn d on d.service_id = p.service_id
       inner join data1.data_priority prio on prio.ingest_data = d.ingest_data
       and p.curated_scheme = %s
       and s.manually_curated_flag = 'Y'
       and s.autosuggest_kind = %s
       limit %s
       offset %s
      )
```

However, this leads to an error of

> Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

To handle that I added alias to my count `select` query but then it returned a wrong output of 1, while the there is around 500 rows in the output table.

Comment: `distinct p.*` it seems wrong to me. Why don't you change `select count(*)` to `select count(some_column)` ?

Comment: Please provide data examples and expected result along with table description

Comment: @ErgestBasha was able to solve the issue by tweaking the query a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try an alias at the end of derived table|subquery

```
select count(*) from(select distinct p.*,d.tech_id, d.id, prio.priority from data.curated_data s
                INNER JOIN data.curated_details p on p.curated_scheme = s.curated_scheme and p.curated_category = s.curated_category
                INNER JOIN data1.data_defn d on d.service_id = p.service_id
                inner join data1.data_priority prio
                on prio.ingest_data = d.ingest_data
                and  p.curated_scheme = %s
                and s.manually_curated_flag = 'Y'
                and s.autosuggest_kind = %s
                limit %s
                offset %s) as temp  ---- here
```

Comment: Tried that. It returns 1 as the output which is incorrect.

Comment: You may need to drill down and check the joins. It maybe possible that query has only 1 record to show. To evaluate you may need to post some sample data as well. Thanks.

Comment: I am sure that it has more than 500 records. When I run the query without the count clause, it returns that many rows. Is there any other way to count no. of rows present in such select statement?